# How do you make text change every time someone refreshes the page?

Tags: html

Is there a way to make text change every time someone refreshes the page?
Basically, I want it to choose from a random text database and select 1 sentence and put it on the website. Is there anyway how?

Comment: It depends on how the data is stored - but what you're asking in itself isn't particularly difficult once that information is known

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript for that :)
Just add a `window.onload()` event that fetches this data from the database and inserts it in the page.

More info about `onload` here - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp